# Discord bot replied multiple times

Tags: python, discord, bots

```
async def on_message(self, msg):
    if msg.author == self.user:
        return

    if msg.content == 'ping':
        await msg.channel.send('pong')


    if "meme" in msg.conent:
        await msg.channel.send('Go to reddit I just have Mommy pics')

    if "gigachad" in msg.content:
        await msg.channel.send('https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/026/152/gigachad.jpg')


    if "amouranth" in msg.content:
        await msg.channel.send('https://files.spieletipps.de/2c/2e/85/839491e6c61a69a14d7d6d9024_ciA2NDIDMmU4NGU2NjE3ZDI=.jpg')

    if "amouranth" in msg.content:
        await msg.channel.send('MOMMY')
```

I wanna close pycharm and pycharm asked if I want to terminate or disconnet so I clicked disconnet so my discord bot was still online but after that I add something and run the bot again and message ping and my bot replied 3x. Cann some help me?

[image]

Comment: sry for the code at the top its my first question

Comment: maybe while coding you launched instances without closing the previous and now you have 3 active (2 in background)... try closing everything.

Comment: @marick thx for the advice but I dont how to close that and when I search I find out that I dont have multiple instance active

Comment: I know it sounds ironic but have you tried restarting your pc? (anyway accept the post edit if you want/can)

Comment: i mean if you write in the discord chat while the pc with the bot is off it doesnt write nothing right?

Comment: sounds like you have three copies of the bot open... somewhere. reboot will definitely fix, or you can try digging through task manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went do discord dev portal and reset the client secret so I was able to run the bot